# Why is IdentityMatrix not defined as a SparseArray by default?

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays, language-design

Simple (possibly silly) question: why are `IdentityMatrix`, `DiagonalMatrix`, `ConstantArray` defined as `List` and not `SparseArray` by default?

I suppose it is due to symbolic computation but I am not sure.

Just to illustrate the question:

```
IdentityMatrix[10000]; // AbsoluteTiming
SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1}, 10000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Of course, `SparseArray` objects also require much less memory.

> {0.113563, Null}
>
> {0.000081, Null}

Comment: Mathematica certainly had these functions before sparse arrays were introduced, so a desire for backwards compatibility might explain it.

Comment: If one is going to be doing many updates to a sparse array, they have their performance downsides....

Comment: You can use `IdentityMatrix[10000, SparseArray]` or `DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[{1, 2}]]`.and `ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}, SparseArray]`

Comment: @user21 Oh, I just posted this as an answer at the exact same time as you... but you have even more ways. Nice!

Comment: @Jens, yeah a bit of a Zufall ;-)

Comment: @user21 Very informative thank you. But it does not answer exactly the question :)

Comment: @anderstood, that's why I put it in as a comment.

Comment: The answer to your question is backwards compatibility.

Comment: `SparseArray[IdentityMatrix[10]]`,`SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[Range@3]]` or `SparseArray[ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}]]`

Comment: `Normal@IdentityMatrix[10000, SparseArray]` is about 4% faster than `IdentityMatrix[10000]` on my machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fastest way to get the identity matrix as a sparse array is simply this:

```
IdentityMatrix[10000, SparseArray]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Here are just some thoughts on why `SparseArray` is not the default for `IdentityMatrix`:

You don't always want `SparseArray` output when defining matrices, and it's not always possible to decide automatically whether a `SparseArray` should be cast into `List` form (simple example: `TraditionalForm` or other displays). Therefore, when `SparseArray` was introduced, it could not simply replace the existing representation of arrays as lists. In particular, this holds for `IdentityMatrix` which is after all of use not only in high-dimensional spaces but also at low dimensionality where `SparseArray` doesn't represent the most efficient way of storing and manipulating arrays. For more potential reasons justifying the default "non-sparseness" of `IdentityMatrix`, see the comments.

Comment: But is there evident reason why this is not the default behaviour?

Comment: @anderstood I think it's a very reasonable behavior, but whether it's "evident" may be a matter of taste, see my update.

Answer (score 7):

`SparseArray` objects are somewhat special and some of the access operations can be slower with them. `IdentityMatrix` though does return a more compact object than just a list of lists -- it returns a packed array.

```
Needs["Developer`"]

Tally[
 Table[PackedArrayQ[IdentityMatrix[n]], {n, Range[1, 1000, 10]}]]

(* {{True, 100}}*)
```

Also, it is really easy to covert the matrices of `IdentityMatrix` into sparse arrays:

```
Table[SparseArray[IdentityMatrix[n]], {n, Range[100, 1000, 100]}]
```

[image: identity matrices]